# Selenium 2 (webdriver) chromedriver cannot find alert for Chrome 29

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, alert, selenium-chromedriver

After Chrome's last release (Version 29.0.1547.66 m) chromedriver cannot find the new chrome alerts. For the previous versions everything worked fine. I also updated the selenium version to 2.9.0 and nothing changed. 
Does someone else have the same issue?
Does it have to do with chrome version or selenium version?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, the latest version of a browser may or may not work with the driver, until the driver has updated their code to work with it. (I've disabled auto-update on all of my browsers for this reason)

Comment: find chrome-driver for your chrome here - https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list What version are you using ?

Comment: chromedriver version is v2.3.220795. I got is from here: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list